# Script to print data into plain text file

Tags: matlab, matrix

```
x=-1:1; 
y=-2:2;
f(x,y)=1-x^2-y^2
```

I want to print the data into a text file with 3 columns: one for `x`, one for `y` and one for `f(x, y)=1-x^2-y^2`. There should be 20 data points for `x`, and 40 for `y`.

Comment: That's impossible. `f(x,y)` *needs* the same amount of data points in both x and y. This doesn't work. Please clarify.

Comment: Please do not delete the questions after you get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you mean a solution on a 21-by-41 points grid you'd need this:

```
x=-1:.1:1;
y=-2:.1:2;
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(x,y); % create grid for file
f=1-x.^2-y.'.^2; % use broadcasting to calculate
totaldata = [xx(:) yy(:) f(:)]; % concatenate into single matrix
fid = fopen('mydat.txt','w') ; % open file
fprintf(fid,'%f %f %f \n',totaldata); % write data
fclose(fid); % close file
```

I'd strongly suggest you to read [The MathWork's own tutorial](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html); not because writing to file is so easy, but because what you wrote up there gives you lots of errors. The first is

```
f(x,y)=1-x^2-y^2
Error using  ^ 
Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix.
To compute elementwise POWER, use POWER (.^) instead.
```

So, using elementwise POWER, as suggested:

```
x=-1:.1:1; 
y=-2:.1:2;
f(x,y)=1-x.^2-y.^2
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

Thus more work is needed. These are basic MATLAB indexing and matrix operations, which is what the entire software is build on. Hence the suggestion to take their own tutorial, or take a course in MATLAB.